# unique index only if field exist

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

If There is a unique index on a field A, then there cannot be 2 documents where A doesn't exist.

How do I specify that the uniqueness should only be enforced on documents where A actually exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume the following object in mongodb

```
[
  {
    "name": "A",
    "phone": 787878
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "phone": 66446
  },
  {
    "name": "C"
  }
]
```

Now you want to make the `phone` variable to be unique upon its existances. You can use the following, `sparse: true` is responsible to check whether the variable is present or not

```
db.collection.createIndex({ phone: 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true })
```

[image: query]

[image: result]

[image: data]

[image: error]

Comment: What about compound indexes? The requirement is to index documents that only contain all fields in the compound index? According to https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-sparse/, it will index docs that contain at least one field